# BBcodes module not working

Tags: nodes

I have installed and enabled [BBcode](https://www.drupal.org/project/bbcode), [BUEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/bueditor), [Extensible BBcode](https://www.drupal.org/project/xbbcode) and [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) modules on my site. I would like use BBcodes to post the topics in forum. When I post the topic with any value [for e.g [b]this is a test data[/b]] and submit the posting I see the raw data displayed without BBcode formatting.

Not sure what is going wrong. I see the errors in the drupal logs.

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character
>   after (?< at offset 5 in XBBCodeFilter->process() (line 42 of
>   /var/web/sites/all/modules/xbbcode/xbbcode.filter.inc).

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

xbbcode maintainer here.

It seems that the module uses a Regex syntax that was introduced in PHP 5.2.2: http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

I'll release a fix when I can; it's a pretty small code change: For each occurrence of `(?<...>` in the pattern, insert a P to make it `(?P<...>`.

Alternatively, you can fix it by upgrading to PHP 5.2.2 or later.

Edit: In fact, Drupal 7's minimum requirements mention PHP 5.2.5 (https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/overview).